# how to read local JSON with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, jsondecoder

I have a local json file and I access the file path with Bundle.main.path function, but I get an error.
[image]

**Service**

```
class Service {
    
    fileprivate var baseURL: String?
    
    init(baseURL: String) {
        self.baseURL = baseURL
    }
    
    func getAllData() {
        AF.request(self.baseURL!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil, requestModifier: .none).response { (responseData) in
            guard let data = responseData.data else { return }
            do {
                let packages = try JSONDecoder().decode(Package.self, from: data)
                print(packages)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View Controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "packageList", ofType: "json") else { return }
        
        let service = Service(baseURL: url)
        service.getAllData()
    }
```

Comment: 1. Why use Alamofire for this? 2. Your url should start with "file://"

Comment: Use `url(forResource: withExtension:)` instead of `path(forResource:ofType:)`.

Comment: if the above worked for you, can you please add it as an answer and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a path (a `String`), so the [`URLConvertible`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/URLConvertible%2BURLRequestConvertible.swift) on String, will call a `URL(string: path)`, which will be invalid in the end, but to make it work, it would need to call `URL(fileURLWithPath: path)` instead.

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "packageList", ofType: "json") else { return }
```

=>

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "packageList", withExtension: "json") else { return }
```

OR

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "packageList", ofType: "json") else { return }
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)`
```

But I'd prefer the first solution, let's avoid a manual conversion.